# SQL injection protection ERROR

Tags: php, html, sql

Am using the following code to protect SQL injection will this work

- am using this in net beans am getting error in `$_POST` the error is `do not access supergloab $_post directly` how do i solve this WARNING MESSAGE

  ```
  $place = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['place']);
  $product = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']);
  $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
  $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
  $mobilebrand = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobilebrand']);
  $mobilemodel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobilemodel']);
  $mobilecond = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobilecond']);
  $price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
  $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
  $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
  $youare = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['youare']);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $phonenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);
  ```

Comment: Try [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) Or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also mysql extension is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956) as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$place = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["place"]);
...
```

Comment: INPUT_POST what does it means

Comment: It's the type of request, i.e. it means you are filtering a POST request. Here are the possible values:
INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, INPUT_ENV

Comment: thank it was valuable

Comment: and what does filte_input means

Comment: It's PHP's function for getting values and filtering them. You can read about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp

Comment: will that protect injection

Comment: Yes it's made for that, it basically does the same as mysql_real_escape_string.